# Binding to ObservableCollection works, but not ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, listcollectionview

I'm trying to get my `ListCollectionView` to bind to a combo box. However, it seems to only work when I bind to my `ObservableCollection`.

Properties:

```
private ListCollectionView sitesView;
public ListCollectionView SitesView
{
        get { return sitesView; }
        set
        {
            sitesView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SitesView);
        }
}
public ObservableCollection<ISite> SitesCollection { get; set; }
```

Constructor:

```
SitesCollection = new ObservableCollection<ISite>();      
SitesView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SitesCollection);
```

When binding like so:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SitesView, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

any item I add to `SitesCollection` does not get shown when I click the drop down in my combo box. But if I do the binding like so:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SitesCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

it works fine and I see the items when I click the drop down.

Attempts at fixing: After I add the an item to the `SitesCollection`, I tried to raise property change notifications on both the `ListCollectionView` and the `ObservableCollection` and it didn't make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually Adam below has the right answer...

Comment: No. This should work. If you don't see the item that you add to the ObservableCollection you are probably binding to the wrong instance of the view model.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time to test my answer; I apologize and will follow up.

I think your issue is because `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(...)`
 returns an `ICollectionView`, which I believe is essentially just a wrapper that enables the underlying data to be sorted.

Try setting `SitesView` to the `SourceCollection` of the `DefaultView`.

```
SitesView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SitesCollection).SourceCollection
```